# Procedure em oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, stored-procedures

Não consigo muito bem criar procedures com os valores de saídas, como receber um valor, e retorna-lo apos a chamada, alguém poderia me ajudar com um exercício que estou com duvidas

**Crie um procedimento que receba o nome de uma determinada peça e
apresente a quantidade total armazenada atualmente desta peça e o local onde se encontra
armazenada a maior quantidade desta peça (Descrição do Corredor e o numero do
Receptáculo).**

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE estoquePeca(pNome IN varchar2) 
   totalArmazenado number;
   localMaiorQuantidade number;
   descricaoCorredor varchar2;
   numeroReceptaculo number;

IS
select sum(p.quant_total) as total, r.num_recept, 
from receptaculos r, pecas p, corredores c
where pNome = p.descricao and p.peca = r.peca and r.cod_corr = c.corredor;

BEGIN

END;
end estoquePeca;
```

[image: estrutura]

Answer (score 1):

Não criei as tabelas para testar, talvez precise de alguns ajustes, mas acredito que isso servirá como uma boa base para aprimorar a `procedure`:

```
--CHAMADA
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    v_maximo number;
    v_total number;
    v_local_desc varchar2(50);
    v_num_recep number;
  BEGIN
    estoquePeca(p_nome => "alguma coisa",
                p_maximo => v_maximo, 
                p_total => v_total, 
                p_local_desc => v_local_desc, 
                p_num_recep => v_num_recep);
    Dbms_Output.put_line(v_maximo);
    Dbms_Output.put_line(v_total);
    Dbms_Output.put_line(v_local_desc);
    Dbms_Output.put_line(v_num_recep);
  END;
END;

-- PROCEDURE
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE estoquePeca(p_nome IN varchar2, 
                                        p_maximo OUT NUMBER, 
                                        p_total OUT NUMBER, 
                                        p_local_desc OUT VARCHAR2(50), 
                                        p_num_recep OUT NUMBER) 
IS 
BEGIN 
   SELECT MAX(r.quant_atual), SUM(r.quant_atual), c.descricao, r.num_recept
     INTO p_maximo, p_total, p_local_desc , p_num_recep
     FROM receptaculos r, pecas p, corredores c
    WHERE p.descricao LIKE '%'||p_nome||'%'
      AND p.peca = r.peca 
      AND r.cod_corr = c.corredor;

END;
/
```